# 2 images or divs next to eachother

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm busy with my first attempt to responsive webdesign and i'm trying to put 2 images next to eachother. When I view the website on a desktop computer the page layout is just fine. But when i'm viewing it on a mobile (or I resize the window) the 2 images at the bottom are not inline anymore and jump on top of eachother.

Any idea how to solve this?
The page is on this test host: www.igga.nl.

Here's my markup:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 568px) {

#footer {
    position: fixed;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    height: 110px;
    border-top: 7px solid #fff;
    background-image: url('../images/bg_footer.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    width: 100%;
}

#pos {
    width: 100%; /* parent */
}
#footer-info {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
#centerpos {
    width: 94%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.tree {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 1.76056338028169% 0 0;
    width: 6.69014084507042%; /* 427 / 960 */
}

.logo-cont {
    border-bottom: 0;
}

.logo {
    margin-top: 18px;
    width: 91.54929577464789%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}
.info-cont {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 2px 0 0 8.45070422535211%;
}

.info {
    margin: 3px 0 0 0;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 0.875em;
}

.info a {
    display: inline;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}

.info-telnr {
    margin: 3px 0 0 0;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 0.875em;
}

.info-telnr h5 {
    display: inline;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 1em;
}
}
```

and this is my HTML:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="pos">
        <div id="footer-info">
            <div id="centerpos">
                    <img class="tree" src="sites/all/themes/md/images/logo_tree.png">   
                <div class="logo-cont">
                    <?php if ($logo): ?>
                    <a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('MD | Illustration & Design'); ?>" rel="home" id="home">
                    <img class="logo" src="<?php print $logo; ?>" alt="<?php print t('MD | Illustration & Design'); ?>" />
                    </a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="info-cont">
                <div class="info">
                    mail&nbsp;<a href="mailto:info@example.nl">info@example.nl</a>
                </div>
                <div class="info-telnr">
                    phone&nbsp;<h5>+31600000000</h5>&nbsp;
                </div>
                <div class="info">
                    shop&nbsp;<a href="http://www.thepossiblemachine.nl" target="_blank">www.thepossiblemachine.nl</a></p>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you want to see when you are in mobile?

Comment: two images next to eachother.
you can see the page at www.igga.nl
i want the tree image and name image next to eachother like how it is when you see the page on a pc.

Comment: then make them 50% width, but on mobile it will look small

Comment: i accidently hit enter on the last comment, i edit that comment to be more precise with my question.

you're right about the 50%. how I have done it now is, a container with 100% width and the images set up with % so it should normally match and be ok for every screen. but it doesn't matter how small i make one of the image, they simply won't get next to eachother. so it has nothing to do that it will not fit in the container.

Comment: show your code, css and html

Comment: Why not make it one image?

Comment: I have included my markup in the start post. I hope it's more clear now.

And I cannot make it into one image because you need to click or copy/paste the urls and text.

Comment: nobody? i'm stuck. please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set float:left for both divs/images. It helps in many cases but I can't tell if it will be useful in your problem without the code. It should look something like:

```
<div id="image1" style="float:left">
   <img src="images/yourimage1" alt=""/>
</div>
<div id="image2" style="float:left">
   <img src="images/yourimage2" alt=""/>
</div>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think his container element will allow this so it breaks to the next line.

Comment: that's right, it will break unfortunately. I have included my markup in my first post. I hope it will make stuff more clear.